# React Native / Firebase Messaging - messages/notifications are never sent

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I am trying to get push notifications / `firebase messaging` to work with react native - I have gotten as far as checking / requesting permission, and I implemented `onMessage`, but I don't get any of my test messages (sent from the `firebase` developer console online, in the `cloud messaging` section). One thing that is odd is when I check the status of a `completed` message, it says no messages were sent (`0 sent`), so I don't even know if my app is getting the chance to receive a test message. Here is my code:

HomeScreen.js (the default route of the root navigator)

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  ....

  componentDidMount() {

    firebase.messaging()
      .hasPermission()
      .then(enabled => {
        if (!enabled) {
          this._getPermission();
        }

        firebase.messaging().getToken()
          .then(fcmToken => {
            if (fcmToken) {
              // user has a device token
            } else {
              alert("User doesn't have a token yet");
            } 
          }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
          });

        firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic('all').catch((error) => {alert(error)});

        this.onTokenRefreshListener = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
            // Process your token as required

        });

        this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
            // Process your message as required
            alert(message);
        });

      }).catch((error) => {alert(error)});
  }

  _getPermission = () => {
    firebase.messaging()
      .requestPermission()
      .catch(error => {
        // User has rejected permissions
        this._getPermission();
      });
  };

  ....

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onTokenRefreshListener();
    this.messageListener();
    firebase.messaging().unsubscribeFromTopic('all');
  }

  ....
```

AppDelegate.h

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import UserNotifications;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@" %@", name);
    }
  }

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"snagit"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

  return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

@end
```

My `BUNDLE_ID`'s all appear to be correct. Why aren't the messages being sent in the first place and/or, why am I not receiving them?

**UPDATE**

Would trying FCM help? https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

**UPDATE**

My request was bad, I got a `curl` try to work with:

> curl -i -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Authorization:
>   key=server-key'
>   -XPOST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{"to": "/topics/all","data": {"message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging
>   Topic Message!"}}'

I received:

```
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 21:38:21 GMT
expires: Tue, 18 Sep 2018 21:38:21 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
server: GSE
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
accept-ranges: none
vary: Accept-Encoding

{"message_id":5323681878653027379}
```

So why doesn't it work coming from the `firebase` web console? Could this be an issue that needs to be resolved by `firebase`?

**UPDATE**

To further test whether or not this is on the `firebase` side of things I wrote a cloud function that should send a notification when a certain document is updated/created/deleted:

```
exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.firestore().document('conversations/{conversationID}/messages/{messageID}').onWrite((change, context) => {

        // Get an object representing the document
        // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
        const newValue = change.after.data();

        // ...or the previous value before this update
        const previousValue = change.before.data();

        // access a particular field as you would any JS property
        //const name = newValue.name;

        var topic = 'all';
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "You got a new Message",
            body: newValue.notification.body,
          }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
      });
```

Here is my code which successfully writes an object to the above `firestore` location:

```
....

constructor() {
    super();

    this.onTokenRefreshListener = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh(fcmToken => {
        // Process your token as required

    });

    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message: RemoteMessage) => {
        // Process your message as required
        alert(message);
    });
    //this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('items');
    //this.authSubscription = null;

}

....

componentDidMount() {

    firebase.messaging().getToken()
          .then(fcmToken => {
            if (fcmToken) {
              console.log(fcmToken);
              // Add a new document with a generated id.
              const addMessage = firebase.firestore().collection('conversations').doc('1234567').collection('messages').doc('1234567');

              data = {
                  notification: {
                    title: "You got a new Message",
                    body: "You got a new message",
                  }
              }
              // Set the 'capital' field of the city
              const updateMessage = addMessage.update(data).catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
                addMessage.set(data).catch((error) => {
                  alert(error);
                });
              });
            } else {
              alert("User doesn't have a token yet");
            } 

          }).catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
          });

    ....

}
```

For output I see the `console.log(fcmToken)` message. When I check the `firebase functions` log, I see `Successfully sent message: { messageId: 6994722519047563000 }`. When I check `firestore`, the document was created (or updated) correctly and it is in the correct place to be noticed (and it is on the `firebase` side according to the `firebase function logs`) - but I still never receive an actual notification on my iPhone.

Why am I not receiving the message if it is being sent?

**UPDATE**

I am now receiving notifications from the logic I created with `firebase functions`, the `firebase` web console just seems like it isn't working - the notifications still never get sent.

Comment: Did you test your code on Android and iOS devices?

Comment: @JeffGuKang no only ios

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

First of all, you need to get push notification in your device (not simulators). 
I recommend to test with iOS and Android devices from firebase web console first. This process is not required codes on your `delegate` files handling push notifications except checking permission.

Anyway, suppose you do not have any android device and it is not working on your iOS device,

1. check bundle ids and GoogleService-Info.plist in firebase and XCode.
2. check your target capabilities on XCode. Push Notifications and Background Mode
   [image]
3. Check app's permission of notification on iOS's setting

## Why?

I am not sure how you set your firebase and XCode, but problems of push notifications from firebase web console are related in permissions, XCode setting and other settings normally.

In my case, typos of the bundle id in firebase settings was the problem.

If you can, you would test on Android also.

Comment: i needed to `return admin.messaging()` function, which I caught in a separate stack question that i asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412488/firebase-functions-admin-messaging-sendtotopic-executes-but-never-makes-it-t